# "no objects or images to bake to " even when texture and object are active

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, texture-baking

The "no objects or images to bake to" error I get when I try to bake. As you can see below it happens to only some objects even though the texture appears active.

[image]

Comment: Internal uses face textures to bake images..image shown in UV/Image editor in Object mode doesn't mean it's active for selected object. So most likely cupboard has image assigned to its faces.. while object on the right hasn't. Checking that is done in Edit mode with all faces selected - if image is shown in UV/Image editor then it's assigned.

Comment: I went to edit mode, made sure all face selected , re-selected the image in UV/image texture and even tried baking in edit mode but still the same error.

Comment: It works as I already mentioned. Aside from that before re-selecting image in UV editor select all uv islands and *then* remove image and assign it back.